# Adjacency Matrix where columns and rows are Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, graph

Need to create a Adjacency matrix where the rows and columns are Strings and the values stored in the matrix are either 0 or 1 which says if there is a connection from the source to dest.

For example: if a->b , b->c are the connections then the matrix should be as follows:

```
a  b  c
```

a 0  1  0

b 0  0  1

c 0  0  0

was searching for a solution to implement this like matrix[a][b] = 1;
which throws an error as we r trying to access the matrix with strings instead of integer positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to code your strings. For example:

```
    Map<String, Integer> codec = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("a", 0);
        put("b", 1);
        put("c", 2);
    }};
    int adjMatrix[][] = new int[][]{
            {0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0}
    };

    System.out.println(adjMatrix[codec.get("a")][codec.get("b")]); //prints "1"
```

Or you can try to use `Map`s:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> adjMatrix = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> aRow = new HashMap<>();
    aRow.put("a", 0);
    aRow.put("b", 1);
    aRow.put("c", 0);
    Map<String, Integer> bRow = new HashMap<>();
    bRow.put("a", 0);
    bRow.put("b", 0);
    bRow.put("c", 1);
    Map<String, Integer> cRow = new HashMap<>();
    cRow.put("a", 0);
    cRow.put("b", 0);
    cRow.put("c", 0);
    adjMatrix.put("a", aRow);
    adjMatrix.put("b", bRow);
    adjMatrix.put("c", cRow);

    System.out.println(adjMatrix.get("a").get("b")); // prints "1"
```